# Getting an empty string at the end of an array returned by method split

Tags: javascript

```js
var s = "Hello, how are you?";
var r = /([,\s?]+)/;
console.log(s.split(r));
```

Why do i get an empty string at the end of the array?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your expression matches a single `?`. If you use `/([,\s]+)/` instead, you'll get `"you?"` as the last element. If you don't want that either, manually remove the last element.

Comment: Because you're splitting on the last character.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this from happening or do i always have to check the string's last character and only then split it?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the question mark after the `\s`.

```js
var s = "Hello, how are you?";
var r = /([,\s]+)/;
console.log(s.split(r));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you ar splitting on the question mark too. Without it:

```js
var s = "Hello, how are you?";
var r = /([,\s]+)/;
console.log(s.split(r));
// including question mark in the split
// and empty values removed from the result
console.log(s.split(/([,\s]+|[?])/).filter(v => v.length));
```